# Winter Bash borked

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

<snark superfluous>Good to see old traditions again,</snark> since [just like last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377742/476), Winter Bash is borked for me:

[image: Oops! Something Bad Happened!]

I cannot login on the https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com site as I get aforementioned error, and while trying to wear hats, I get a nondescript *"An error occurred while changing the hat"* message (which I'm sure is entirely unrelated ;-P).

You may want to look into this.

Comment: Can you log in to https://stackexchange.com/? (Just a hunch that it may be related, if you can't.)

Comment: I *am logged in* on stackexchange.com.

Comment: I don't really feel like logging out of everything, but I've logged in on another browser to stackexchange.com and then tried to sign into the WB2019 page → same error.

Comment: Any software on your system that prevents certain types of connections or software?

Comment: @Luuklag No. I even explicitly tried disabling content blockers.

Comment: @Eran That *shouldn't* influence anything, and I'd like to keep my history thankyouverymuch, and if that *is* the cause of any problem then SE should fix it, since they can't expect everyone to clear their history.

Comment: I suppose the hats just don't fit onto the headphones ... :)

Comment: @Jonas That actually *is* an issue, I'd like to ask for more inclusive headgear next year!

Comment: An "unexpected error"? That was...unexpected.

Comment: So, anyone else suddenly wishing for a Swedish Chef hat? (Bork!Bork!Bork!)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Something hokey happened the first time that you tried to do something with a hat. I cleared out your data and it repopulated with the scheduled task. Can you please try to log in again?

**Update**: weird data situation fixed, all is working now

Comment: Any chance for gory details? ;-)

Comment: Combination of user-inits on specific sites for this account in the past that went awry (leaving multiple phantom user records on those sites), those not getting cleaned up, and the network api call being used to retrieve them not filtering them out. And the WB code expecting (rightly) to get one row per account/site.

Comment: Sounds like my code!! lol... good thing you caught it so fast. So, you added some sanity checks to the code?

Comment: May I feel special in that I was the only one with such data? Or are you currently crawling around the air vents to clean up loads of messed up data?