# Suggestions for Winter Bash 2020

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

Winter Bash 2019 is almost over, and as it's the new year, it's now time to open up the [recurring question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321554/suggestions-for-winter-bash-2019) for the next Winter Bash.

Please post your suggestions regarding how to make Winter Bash 2020 even more fun than the previous Winter Bashes.

- New suggestions for hats and hat triggers (either regular or secret ones)
- Which hats should be kept?
- Which hats should be retired?
- Do we want more secret hats?
- Do we want more or fewer secret hats that don't get triggered until long after the start of Winter Bash?

Yes, I'm aware of recent events (such as the departure of balpha, the long-time SE employee once responsible for the fun Winter Bash ideas), but in the spirit of tradition and in order to ensure our feedback is taken, I'm opening this.

Of course, let's still keep the traditional format of one suggestion per answer, so people can vote on individual suggestions.

If you prefer that there be something other than the traditional hat format for the winter 2020 celebration, please say what specific thing you'd prefer in an answer.

Comment: what makes you think hats will return, period?

Comment: Almost certainly, [no hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321554/suggestions-for-winter-bash-2019/321862#comment1052792_321554) - there's a [reason for hats *this* year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337910/winter-bash-2019-is-it-happening-this-year#comment1134022_339591), otherwise we would have had something else. There are [non-hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337932/282094) suggestion**s** already put forth; as a minimum those answers should be moved here if this stays open.

Comment: It is worth noting that it is in SE's best interest to host a winter end-of-year celebration - traffic falls low during that time, and these celebrations help keep users on the site during that time.

Comment: @David Hats are always in style

Comment: Why's this getting downvoted so heavily? Doesn't anyone want to celebrate winter bash? It's my first time, I would love to.

Comment: It is happening: https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 8):

From what I've seen, people may want something different from hats...

Here's some (kinda strange) ideas I've had for a while...

A network/meta scavenger hunt to find a secret webpage for a prize?

---

Inspired by people sharing their knitting artwork (my personal favourite thing about the Bash), a very small Mario-Paint like composer. (I know it sounds a bit strange...)

---

A snowman builder/igloo decorating or something like that. (still inspired by knitting)

---

If I get any more ideas I'll add to this answer.

Comment: We did have this in previous years' Winter Bashes; we would have likely seen one this year had balpha not left the company. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=the+quest+for+the+winter+chickens

Comment: You just COPIED my idea! How could you!

Comment: Sorry ^_^;  Which one? I can remove it from my list if you'd like

Comment: The snowflake one.

Comment: I've removed it ^_^;

Answer (score 6):

For Werewolf Hunter certainly yeah, it has to go, it didn't provide help to old posts, instead it provided work from moderators, to rollback, everyone just randomly pokes in and out few characters which doesn't help at all.

Well, very possible no bash next year tho...

Comment: Which is already done: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340049/retire-werewolf-hunter

Answer (score 2):

To start on a honest note, I [didn't expect Winter Bash to happen this year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337910/winter-bash-2019-is-it-happening-this-year), so kudos to [the WB team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340797/are-secret-hat-triggers-different-for-employees-of-stack-exchange/340809#340809) for running it, fixing [all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340054/winter-bash-borked) [the](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339950/winter-bash-hat-not-being-awarded-for-gold-badge-on-main-sites) [bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340556/the-blue-in-the-face-hat-seems-to-have-the-same-trigger-as-007) and implementing [the](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340512/this-star-on-the-warm-welcome-hat-looks-like-a-communist-symbol) [various](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340049/retire-werewolf-hunter) [suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340827/winter-bash-stats-page-is-listing-the-stats-from-2017).

---

**My suggestion:**

While I totally understand that the SE team's [been busy lately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337910/winter-bash-2019-is-it-happening-this-year#comment1134022_339591), I have to say that I'm a tad disappointed that all of this year's WB hats (as in the hat designs, not the triggers) were reused and some of the chosen hats aren't just reused once but multiple times in the past.

So, *if* there's gonna be hats next year and there's still not enough time to design new ones, ***can we please retire these hats*** that have been reused a whopping 3 and 4 times:

- **4 times:** Scarf Ace, Amazing Grace, Silencium
- **3 times:** Glasses With A Number On Top, Just Jesting, The Milliner, Hero Of Time, Werewolf Hunter, Fashionable, Red Baron, Foot of the Rainbow, This Is Fine, 007

There are many other hats from Hat Dash and the earlier WBs that were not reused before and I suggest they ["[return] to the Winter Bash stage for a repeat performance"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/12/12/winter-bash-2017-greatest-hits-hats/).

And additionally, if possible, I really hope to see at least a few new hats in future WBs, something similar to WB2017 where 6 of 33 hats were new or even to WB2018, where half of the hats were new.

Answer (score -2):

This year we still don't have flagging hats, last year we didn't as well, we should have flagging hats next year, like, 2017 Ooh Shiny, which was missing.

That's the other point.

Comment: remember, it is not likely that this year will have hats.

Comment: @zixuan but we will, it's already confirmed for sure by several employees of SE.

Answer (score -5):

How about changing the name to COVID BASH 2020.

With different masks for prizes; instead, of hats?

Comment: No. Having a "mask hat" is enough to remind people of the COVID in a funny way, without making too big fuss.

Comment: Ughh, mask hat is enough. Why change tradition due to covid?