# Why break the tradition?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

It all started out in 2011 on the Gaming Stack Exchange under the name of [**Hat Dash**](https://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/).

Participants of Arqade really liked it, and in 2012, it became a fun event for the whole Stack Exchange network called [**Winter Bash**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/12/19/welcome-to-winter-bash-2012/). There were more and more people participating in it. And everybody loved it.

This year, Stack Exchange have been through really hard times, because they have done many, many mistakes. However, they still found time and effort to organise [**Winter Bash 2019**](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/).

However, it seems people got bored with Winter Bash.

> As an aside, I would love to hear suggestions from people that have
>   nothing to do with hats. This was the 8th year we've done the same
>   thing with different triggers and to be honest, I turned them off this
>   year because I've gotten kind of bored with the idea. — [animuson ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321554/suggestions-for-winter-bash-2019/321862#comment1052792_321554)

So here are obvious questions:

- Why can't we have Winter Bash 2020?
- If you got bored with the idea, I guess you are also bored with celebrating New Year, Christmas and all the rest of annual events.
- Even if you are bored, can't we just change the main topic of the event? Change hats to vehicles for example, like it was [suggested by Rob](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337932/403480) in Winter Bash 2019 suggestions.

Personally I really look forward to having Winter Bash 2020.

Comment: I think you seem to be confusing the term Winter Bash to exclusively mean "Winter Bash with Hats". My understanding (which could very well be wrong) is that WB is the term for the event and that we will likely still have WB2020, but they are looking for hat-free suggestions for it.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341367/suggestions-for-winter-bash-2020#comment1142071_341367

Comment: I *am* pretty bored with celebrating New Years... 2020 is a nice round number - maybe we can just stick with that for a decade or so?

Comment: @VerNicksaysReinstateMonica Can you explain what that comment is supposed to tell me? I don't see it's relevance (could just be missing it).

Comment: *If you got bored with the idea, I guess you are also bored with celebrating New Year, Christmas and all the rest of annual events.* I forget which fallacy this is, but it is one.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose It just says "no hats".

Comment: @VerNicksaysReinstateMonica Right. I still don't understand what it has to do with what I said... Perhaps we are talking past each other? Then again, it is very much not vital, it was a rather minor point on my part.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Oh no, I clearly get everything you say. I just want you to consider those points about Winter Bash just in case.

Comment: Personally, WB has always been my favourite event here. (most likely because of the chance to share knittings). I like the idea of trying something new for Winter Bash.

Comment: @EleezatheCharacterWizard Do you want to leave the main topic the same, with changing user avatars, or something entirely new?

Comment: @VerNicksaysReinstateMonica I think it depends on if people just want to get rid of hats completely, or if they want something alongside the hats. I never paid much attention to hats, I'm here for the knitting.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi False Equivalence is the fallacy you are looking for https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=false+equivalence

Comment: @Shog9 11111100100 isn't a nice round number. 100000000000 is.

Comment: " it seems people got bored with Winter Bash." Is this really true? How many people opted into the Winter bash this year compared to last years?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It is more than one: straw man, slippery slope, *non sequitur*, faulty analogy, and possibly hasty generalization. A good list can be found [here](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/fallacies_list.html). Wikipedia also maintains [one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies).

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Ok, I am really sorry for misunderstanding. I thought "no hats" meant "no WB", but it meant "no WB with hats".

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: [*Appeal to Tradition*](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Appeal_to_tradition) [X is a tradition, therefore X is good] and [*Overgeneralization*](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Overgeneralization) [some traditions are good; therefore all traditions are good].

Comment: Way too many assumptions here. For example, animuson is just one person, and not in position to decide whether to have WB or not, company-wise. We can't know what will happen or what they'll do, but assuming there won't be winter bash because one (or even few) employee is bored is very far fetched, IMO.

Comment: _"If you got bored with the idea, I guess you are also bored with celebrating New Year, Christmas and all the rest of annual events."_ What a silly thing to say!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Why break the tradition?

Counter question: what gives meaning to such traditions?

For me, that people want them, and enjoy them. Traditions that don't lift you up  are pointless.

So, I think there are two aspects here:

- The whole *mess* since September, and all the other things during the last years ... that ate up a lot of motivation. It feels like the "house" is on flames, and well, then people aren't so much in party mood in the first place.
- And maybe, just maybe, the idea really wore out. It should be easy to do statistics, and compare them to previous years. (I think there were some already, suggesting that participation declined pretty much). When a lot of users who really don't care about "the mess" didn't wear hats, too ... then maybe: it would be time to let that go.

My suggestion: simply forget about it *for now*. For me personally, I have no clue right now if I *want* to be around any SE Inc. hosted network site by the end of 2020. I worry much more about what SE Inc. will do during the next weeks at this point (remember their [vision statement](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/11/the-loop-1-how-we-conduct-research-on-the-community-team/) when they announced "the loop"?)

Thus: there is really no urgency here. I don't see why we would need to push for a WinterBash 2020, with hats, or with vehicles, or something completely different *right now*.

Let's see if there is still "a house" for us in 3, 6, 9 months. And if so, *then* I am fine discussing what the majority would like to see.

Comment: That's a good point about it, especially about considering the future actions of SE Inc. Thanks for clear answer.

Comment: @VerNicksaysReinstateMonica You are very welcome. Giving clear answers, that is what I am still here ;-)

Comment: Well, you are also here to reinstate Monica I suppose ;)

Comment: I didn't even put on a hat this year. I just got as many as I could (all but one) to hopefully force a Monica reference into the Blog.

Comment: @VerNicksaysReinstateMonica I was. Now I am mainly here to remind folks about her name, and add more glory ... in a similar way to what X27 tried.

Comment: @X-27wantstoReinstateMonica That is a really neat idea. Is there now an official blog entry with your name, or when should that show up?

Comment: @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC. Every other year there has been a blog post after the winter bash ended, mentioning things like how many of each hat were earned, who got the most, and usually a screenshot of the top of the leaderboard. If the do one this year, it should show up any day now.

Answer (score 1):

The difference could be split by having half of the conditions trigger hats, and half of them doing something else. That way people who love hats and people who are bored with them can both be satisfied.