# Will we have a winter bash 2020 this year?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, fun, winter-bash-2020

(or some other end of year fun?)

At the end of last year, there was discussion suggesting that "winter bash 2019" (with the hat thing) was the last one (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341555/400547) to learn more).

Now that December is near, I would like to know if the 2019 winter bash (with the hat thing) was indeed the last one? And if yes, is there some other fun stuff planned?

Given the current pandemic event (and lockdown in lots of countries, including mine), I really look forward to having some fun things to do online and I'm hoping that SE will provide some of this fun.

Comment: I hope so... little distraction would not hurt :)

Comment: Instead of hats, maybe we can all [safety dance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjPau5QYtYs).

Comment: Winterbash is on the Q4 roadmap: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355660/158100

Comment: I think it's fair to have a question specifically about this rather than closing it as a duplicate of a larger post. :)

Comment: Agree with @Catija, especially when the larger post links to a blog post with the answer, i.e. doesn't even have the direct answer to begin with.

Comment: Well, there certainly were objections to the previous one: [Winter Bash 2019 - is it happening this year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337910)

Comment: It should be masks rather than hats this year.

Comment: @Lundin I don't remember where I read it, but I do know that we will have a mask indeed (though probably just one)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes! As said in [The Loop: Our Community Roadmap for Q4 2020](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/10/21/the-loop-our-community-roadmap-for-q4-2020/) blog post:

> **Winter Bash and Stack Gives Back**
> It’s Q4, and that means it’s time for our favorite Winter events. This year you’ll see some fun new hats as we work to refresh the contest and introduce some new challenges for Winter Bash.

Comment: I wonder what the chances are of someone misinterpreting the 10 years thing and your account getting flagged for being an underage user :p (Joking aside - congrats!)

Comment: @JonClements https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8604753#8604753 ;)

Comment: @JonClements has made a  good point.  I shall be flagging you directly.  Naughty Shadow!

Answer (score 18):

And it’s official ...

The [Winter Bash 2020 countdown page](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/) is up!

Seems like it’ll start around Dec 16.

Comment: Oh, that's really cool! I didn't know winter bash countdown were a thing!

Comment: Looking forward to it, as always.

Comment: @BelovedFool yes, it became standard in the last few years, think 3 or 4 years. Used to be snow, now Yaakov made something else.

Comment: If you disable javascript, the countdown sais 0.