# Will there be a Winter Bash 2021 this year?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, fun, winter-bash-2021

Are we having a Winter Bash this year?
I really hope so.

Usually this late in November the countdown page is already up.

[In 2020 it was up by November 24th](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357046/191412).

[In 2018 it was up by November 23rd](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318712/191412).

[In 2019 the countdown did come late (early December), so maybe there's still hope](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339591/191412)...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So, I checked the **accepted answer** to the same question which was asked last year: [Will we have a winter bash 2020 this year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356190/369802). Not sure why you left that one out of your search results, but it would've given you your answer.

Because [the accepted answer to last year's question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/356191/369802) linked to the roadmap from the 'The Loop' blog posts.

So, I checked the roadmap for [Q4 2021](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/09/19/the-loop-our-community-department-roadmap-for-q4-2021/) and that one does indeed include winter bash.

Comment: Like I said, it's about the **accepted answer** to that question, and I know you linked to one that suited the narrative in your question better. Point is, it made this information so trivial to find....

Comment: I concur. Answer endorsed.

Answer (score 32):

[Countdown has started](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/) - Winter Bash 2021 will start December 15th, but at an unusual time: *noon* instead of midnight (UTC).

Comment: That's a much better start time as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: This countdown is beautiful!

Comment: Thanks, @Glorfindel.  Much friendlier and straightforward of an answer.  The link is an added bonus!

Comment: Thank you @amWhy. To Tinkeringbell's defense: the countdown page did not exist when she wrote her answer :)

Comment: Even though I'm in the northern hemisphere (where it is indeed winter, very definitely), I approve of the summer option for our southern friends.  Now, if only you could make our days a bit longer to match...

Comment: The CMs told all diamond moderators 12+ days in advance, or just Meta.SE ones?

Comment: @user1271772 no, why? That was just the launch of the [countdown page](http://web.archive.org/web/20211203172236/https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/) we get to see every year...